# unable to read file from external location in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

### I am trying to read a txt file(kept in another location) in python, but getting error.

> FileNotFoundError
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 employeeFile=open("C:‪/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/python/files/employee.txt","r")
>         2 print(employeeFile.read())
>         3 employeeFile.close()
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory:'C:\u202a/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/python/files/employee.txt'

Code used:

```
 employeeFile=open("C:‪/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/python/files/employee.txt","r")
    print(employeeFile.read())
    employeeFile.close()
```

I tried using frontslash(/) and backslash(). But getting the same error.Please let me know what is missing in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you copy and pasted from a Windows property pane, switching backslashes to forward slashes manually. Problem is, the properties dialog shoves a Unicode LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING character into the path so the display is consistent, even in locales with right-to-left languages (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew).

You can read more about this on [Raymond Chen's blog, The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924/). The solution is to delete that invisible character from your path string. Selecting everything from the initial `"` to the first forward slash, deleting it, then retyping `"C:/`, should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message suggests, there's a weird character between the colon and the forward slash (`C:[some character]/`). Other than that the code is fine.

```py
employeeFile = open("C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/python/files/employee.txt", "r")
```

You can copy paste this code and use it.